# How to handle multiple virtualhost (w/ alias) on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-xp, virtualhost

Well,

I know how to do virtual hosts, but on windows it looks harder to get what i want to.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domaindev.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/domaindev_com/public"
    ServerName domaindev.com
    ServerAlias *.domaindev.com
    ErrorLog "logs/domaindev_com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domaindev_com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And my *hosts* file:

```
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.

127.0.0.1      localhost
192.168.0.1    domaindev.com
192.168.0.1    www.domaindev.com

C:\Documents and Settings\B>ping domaindev.com

Pinging domaindev.com [192.168.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Documents and Settings\B>ping www.domaindev.com

Pinging www.domaindev.com [192.168.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

So it looks like it works.
But when i try to use the www.domaindev.com in my browser i get a time out or a dns failure...

Any ideas ?
Is the ServerAlias option wrong ?

**EDIT:** Only the domaindev.com is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested changing the `ServerAlias` directive to the absolute URL `www.domaindev.com` and trying that?

Your browser may have also cached the failed DNS request and hasn't tried it again - usually killing all browser sessions will help with that.

Answer (score 0):

These configuration files are on a server, right?  And the browser you're trying to load it up in is on your personal machine, not the server?  Because, see, when you put `192.168.0.1 www.domaindev.com` in the hosts file, it only makes it resolve on that machine, not any other.  Try putting it in your workstation's hosts file too.

Comment: Both server and browser are on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the site via domaindev.com? via the ip address? If you can't it's not a resolution problem but an apache config/startup problem as the server is not running.

Comment: I'm able to access to domaindev.com (and ip address)

Comment: hmm, this _shouldn't_ make a difference but i would try to adjust your hosts file to have 1 192 line so i would read '192.168.0.1 domaindev.com www.domaindev.com' also i would try putting domaindev.com and wwww.domaindev.com on the 127.0.0.1 line once again _shouldn't_ make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any active proxy configuration in your webbrowser? Try to deactivate the proxy. Sometimes the command "ipconfig /flushdns" exectued in a command prompt helps.

Have you already tried to connect to your website with "domaindev.com"? If this works than you have to change your ServerAlias directive to an fqdn.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: ServerName directive is required as the fqdn - the ServerAlias is not.